# How to store a double in an array incrementally

Tags: java

this is my first post and I hope someone can help. I have been struggling for ages to understand the problem I have and it looks as though I have done everything right yet problem persists. I have written a simple account program and would like to store the new balance after each transaction into an array index. From printing out balance I can see that it is adding and subtracting properly, however it is updating every single array index with the new balance rather than each incremental index. Can anyone spot my mistake. Thank you for any help with this.

Richard

```
public class TestAppAccount {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int count = 0;

    do {
        AppAccount.transaction();
        AppAccount.storeBalance();
        AppAccount.printBalance();
        count++;
        //Account1.printBalance2();
    } while (count <= 100);

}

public class AppAccount {

    public static double[] currentBalance = new double[100];
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static double balance;
    static int transaction;


    public static void transaction() {
        System.out.println(" Press 1 to add funds, 2 to withdraw ");
        transaction = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (transaction == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to add ");
            double amount = keyboard.nextInt();
            double newBalance = balance + amount;
            balance = newBalance;
        } else

        {
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to withdraw");
            double amount = keyboard.nextInt();
            double newBalance = balance - amount;
            balance = newBalance;
        }
    }

    public static void storeBalance() {
        for (int i = 0; i < currentBalance.length; i++) {
            currentBalance[i] = balance;

        }

    }

    public static void printBalance() {
        System.out.println("Balance: " + balance);
        System.out.println("Balance: " + currentBalance[3]);//testing by printing 3rd index
    }
}
```

Comment: Here? `public static void storeBalance() {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentBalance.length; i++) {
        currentBalance[i] = balance;

    }

}`

Comment: The first mistake is storing a balance in a double. Never use floating point variables for storing amounts of money.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by each incremental index? also, I might be missing something, but it looks like you never actually use the array. storeBalance() doesn't seem to ever get called.

Comment: @Robert I wish I could upvote that comment more than once. **Never** use floating point for money. Use a `long` and store it as whole numbers of cents, or use `BigDecimal`. Also, don't make everything `static`, don't make the balance `public`, use data hiding and encapsulation. Read up on object oriented design.

Answer (score 1):

Your storeBalance() method is iterating through the entire array and updating the values. If you want to only update one value, you'll need to keep track of where you've written up to and only write to the location one after that.

e.g.

Instead of

```
public static void storeBalance() {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentBalance.length; i++) {
        currentBalance[i] = balance;
    }
}
```

try this:

```
static int lastStored = 0;
public static void storeBalance() {
    currentBalance[lastStored++] = balance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < currentBalance.length; i++) {
    currentBalance[i] = balance;

    }
```

That for loop is setting every value in the array to the value of balance. If each index is supposed to be a different account I would suggest passing an index to each function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
public static void storeBalance() {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentBalance.length; i++) {
        currentBalance[i] = balance;
    }  
}
```

That for-loop will step through *every* element in the array, one by one, and will overwrite *each* value with whatever the current `balance` is.

There are a couple of ways you could fix this. My first reaction would be to create a variable that tells you the next index to write to:

```
static int nextIndex = 0;
```

and then `storeBalance()` would look like this:

```
public static void storeBalance() {
    currentBalance[nextIndex] = balance;
    nextIndex++;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to make the `nextIndex` static if you want to use it in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is you do a `for` loop and update every single value.  You just want to update once when `storeBalance()` is called. Keep track of `i` as a `static` variable:

```
static int i = 0;
```

Then do this:

```
public static void storeBalance() {
    if(i >= currentbalance.length)
        i = 0;//restart value so it doesnt do array out of bounds
    currentbalance[i] = balance;//update a single value
    i++;//increment for next call
}
```

Make sure you do the out of bounds check.  That's what the other answers are forgetting to check.  Of course this will over write old values, so you can choose to do something else (what ever seems fitting for your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Stop pretending that java is c.
Java is not c.
Java likes objects.
Use objects.
Avoid arrays.

Here is some code:

```
// start Main.java file

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int count = 0;

        do
        {
            AppAccount.transaction();
            AppAccount.storeBalance();
            AppAccount.printBalance();
            count += 1;
        }
        while (count <= 4);

    }
}

// start AppAccount.java file

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppAccount
{
    private static List<Double> currentBalanceList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static double runningBalance;
    private static int transaction;

    public static void printBalance()
    {
        System.out.println("Running Balance: " + runningBalance);
    }

    public static void storeBalance()
    {
        currentBalanceList.add(runningBalance);
    }

    public static void transaction()
    {
        double amount;

        System.out.println(" Press 1 to add funds, 2 to withdraw ");
        transaction = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (transaction == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to add ");
            amount = keyboard.nextDouble();
            runningBalance = runningBalance + amount;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to withdraw");
            amount = keyboard.nextDouble();
            runningBalance = runningBalance - amount;
        }
    }
}
```